# Why is my password hashing function leading to data not being saved in the session? (PHP)

Tags: php, encryption, hash

I am using the following two functions to hash passwords on a registration form:

```
function password_encrypt($password){
    $hash_format = "$2y$10$"; //2y means use blowfish. 10 is cost parameter - number of times to run the blowfish hash.
    //Blowfish wants salts of 22 characters or more.
    $salt_length = 22;

    $salt = generate_salt($salt_length);
    $format_and_salt =  $hash_format . $salt;

    $hash = crypt($password, $format_and_salt); ///If this was echoed, salt would appear at beginning as part of result.
    //Means hash can be passed in again as a salt. Then the has contains the salt making it easy to compare.
    return $hash;
}

function generate_salt($length){
    //MD5 returns 32 characters
    $unique_random_string = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

    //Valid characters for a salt are [a-zA-Z0-9./]
    $base64_string = base64_encode($unique_random_string);

    //But not '+' which is valid in base 64 encoding (base 64 encode returns '+' when it should be '.')
    $modified_base64_string = str_replace('+','.', $base64_string);

    //Truncate string to the correct length
    $salt = substr($modified_base64_string, 0, $length);

    return $salt;
}
```

When I run a check of the password with the following, data isn't being saved in the session:

```
if(!empty($User)&& !empty($Pass)){

            $Pass = password_encrypt($Pass); 

            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE '$User' = login AND '$Pass' = password";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)
            or die ('Error: '.mysql_error());

            //If query produces nothing
            if(!$query){
                $Message = "Incorrect username and/or password.";
            }else{
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    ///TODO Store user id in session as well
                    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row["first_name"];
                    $_SESSION['group_id'] = $row["group_id"];
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row["user_id"];
                }

            redirect_to('dashboard.php');
        }


        }
```

When I use plain text passwords instead of hashing the data is saved into the session correctly, however, when I use the hashing functions, accessing the session data I intended to save produces an error which says that, for example, the $_SESSION['user_id'] is an undefined index. Is there something wrong with the hashing methods?

Comment: just a note; you should be using OOP mysqli you've got a vulnerability in your $query variable. will look into your other problem now.

Comment: $query is a string, so `if(!$query)` won't ever evalute false. You might want to check if `$result` is actually not empty, and you must count it beforehand in ordere to do so.

Comment: 1. You should use the built in password hashing functionality instead : http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php 2. Undefined index isn't an error, it's a notice. But you should make sure that the session has started, which isn't in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The code is buggy and insecure and isn't going to work - the thread will never get to the point of trying to populate the session. But your question implies that you think it is getting there and there's something wrong with the session. There isn't.

The most elementary part of fault finding is isolating the problem - there are lots of ways of doing this, but instrumenting your code is a very simple way to do so. If you had you would know that your problem has nothing to do with the session.

You've not understood how salted hashes and initialization vectors work - you need to retrieved the hash from the password based on the suplied username then run it through crypt again in PHP land. There are lots of examples on the internet on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not escaping characters in your encrypt password function:

$2aVOhEz8P7i6 will look for the variable '2aVOhEz8P7i6' which isn't set.

EDIT:

echo password_encrypt('hello');
= $2aVOhEz8P7i6

EDIT2:

also:

`"SELECT * FROM users WHERE '$User' = login AND '$Pass' = password"`

should be

`"SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$User' AND password = '$Pass'"`

for readability.